# How to use VS 2012 merge tool with Git and the Git SCP

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, git-extensions

I have Git. I have Git Extensions. I have the Git Source Control Provider for Visual Studio 2012. I cannot see how it all comes together.

The Git SCP, just gives me a commit UI and the rest calls out to Git Extensions. If I right-click the Conflict file in the Pending Changes window, there's no option to resolve in the VS merge tool.

If I right-click the file in the Solution Explorer, I have an option within a sub-menu to Solve Merge Conflict, but this also just opens Git Extensions.

What is going on? I am at my wits end with Git.

Comment: (I know how it feels to be at wits end with Git!) I suggest you use Git from the command line or the GitGUI comes with: http://git-scm.com/downloads

Comment: Thanks for the moral support, I mean it. I feel there's peer pressure to like it.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into similar problems. You can specify which diff tool to use by going to Tools->Options->Source Control. Select "Git Source Control Provider" from the drop down. Then, back in the tree on the left you should see the TFS options disappear and one for "Git Source COntrol Provider Options" show up. Click on that and then you will see options for which diff tool to use.